# Can add ListView items without using Adapter? too cumbersome for static array display

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I'd like to implement ListView and each item have multiple tags like StackOverflow list (a kind of master-detail style view).
Each tag in items is enumerated by `tags` string array.

The tags are no need to be changed/filtered when it first showed so that I think it does NOT need to use an adapter (an adapter is for binding between data model and view, right?). Moreover, I think using adapter in each item may cause performance issue in order to process additional bindings.

Is there any workaround to add `ListView` items without using `Adapter`?

For reference, in C#, `listView.Items.Add("item1");` can display items simply.

Comment: So basically you want to show items in listview without creating any adapter, am I right?

Comment: @Android-Developer // Yes. exactly. but need to be styled(colored box) on each item so that array.toString() with TextView is not adaquate for me.

Comment: You cannot add/show any items to list view without creating any adapters.

Comment: Thanks. So I need to write more code on that. :$

Comment: can you show with a sample what really you are trying to achieve because 'StackOverflow list' doesn't say anything to me.

Comment: @Android-Developer // not a big thing. I just intend "each item has multiple tags" in a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Android-Developer noted, it is impossible to add arrays to ListView without `Adapter`.

```
listViewTopics.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Topic>(CurrentActivity.this, R.layout.item_tag, topics));
```

above single-line code is simplist way to show array items(`topics` in this example) to `ListView`.

Comment: If you are using custom object like `Topic`  instead of string you would be using custom XML for single item and also logic code for how to extract and populate data from custom object into xml, but you could avoid it if you have a list of strings by using `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`

Answer (score 5):

There is no option to create list with adapter. but yes you can use the default Array Adapter for list view.

```
List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
values.add("Lesson 1.");
values.add("Lesson 2.");
values.add("Lesson 3.");
values.add("Lesson 4.");

ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);

listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

In string.xml do this first..

```
<string-array name="Entries">
<item>Item 1</item>
<item>Item 2</item>
<item>Item 3</item>
</string-array>
```

Then do this in your ListView in xml..

```
<ListView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:entries="@array/Entries"></ListView>
```

Comment: You make me to know new knowledge. thanks. Can it be achieved by code only? my question was about not resource-fixed, but programmatically generated.